# C# Regex repeating match between 2 literals

Tags: c#, regex

I extract a string from a pdf from that string I need to get a list of tracking numbers.

My extracted string is like this were "more text" is all the rest of the extracted string.

more text...__FREIGHT: 0.00__SALES TAX: 0.00 __602256510000; 602256510002; 602256500001; TRACKING...more text

I locate the tracking numbers in the string by matching on "TRACKING".
Here is my Regex:

```
((?<TrackingNumber>[a-zA-Z0-9]+);\s)+TRACKING
```

Here's the problem:
after execution the Group TrackingNumber" only contains the last tracking number, but as stated above in need The Group "TrackingNumber" to have 3 matches, one for each tracking number (without the trailing ";" or space)

Comment: our regex is same as https://regex101.com/r/cH1gS7/4 . You can't do like the above eventhough if you use non-greedy quantifier.

Comment: You cannot match all individual matches for a repeating group; you will always only match the last one. You need to extract them in two steps: Extract the sequence and then split it by the semicolon.

Comment: try https://regex101.com/r/cH1gS7/5

Comment: @poke - Not true in Dot-Net, even though the _last_ capture will always be overwritten, it has a capture collections array for each group to store (push) values onto.

Comment: @sln Oh, nice! Good to know, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try the below `\G` anchored based regex

```
(?:;\s|_)(?<TrackingNumber>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=.*?;\s*TRACKING)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cH1gS7/7)

Comment: works well. but it fails on this: hk__hkh__602256510000; 602256510002; 602256500001; TRACKING hghg 65656676; ghg

Comment: This is not correct. The `\G` anchor is useless, never gets matched, and all this regex does is use a lookahead for anything waaayyy.. downstream that ends in `;\s*TRACKING.`

Answer (score 1):

The way its done in Dot-Net is to use *Capture Collections*

---

*edit:* - note that you may want to make the tracking chars optional
`[a-zA-Z0-9]*` incase there is a missing/blank number mid-stream.
This will continue capturing.
(example: `602256510000; 602256510002;; 602256500001; TRACKING`)

---

```
 # (?:(?<TrackingNumber>[a-zA-Z0-9]+);\s)+TRACKING

 (?:
      (?<TrackingNumber> [a-zA-Z0-9]+ )  #_(1)         
      ; \s 
 )+
 TRACKING
```

C#:

```
string pdf = "__602256510000; 602256510002; 602256500001; TRACKING ";
Regex RxTrack = new Regex(@"(?:(?<TrackingNumber>[a-zA-Z0-9]+);\s)+TRACKING");

Match trackMatch = RxTrack.Match( pdf );
if ( trackMatch.Success )
{
    CaptureCollection cc = trackMatch.Groups["TrackingNumber"].Captures;
    for (int i = 0; i < cc.Count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] = {1}", i, cc[i].Value);
}
```

Output:

```
[0] = 602256510000
[1] = 602256510002
[2] = 602256500001
```

Answer (score 0):

this regex can take it

```
(?<TrackingNumber>[\d]+)(?=;)
```

Comment: I updated my question, can you expand this for my additional requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you.

```
(?<TrackingNumber>[0-9]+)(?=.*?;\sTRACKING)
```

And for better understanding check this :
[Regular Expression Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: this did not give 3 matches, only 2. 1st) TRACKING 2nd) 602256510000; 602256510002; 602256500001;  (TrackingNumber)

Comment: sry... i did not read well your question. i have updated to respect the exact string that you need.

Comment: your update gives too many matches:  I need to stop backward matching once "__" is matched. Here is more of the string ==>...__FREIGHT: 0.00__SALES TAX: 0.00__602256510000; 602256510002; 602256500001; TRACKING

Comment: what you can do if the TrackingNumber has always len = 12 or between 10 and 12 then (?<TrackingNumber>[0-9]{10,12})(?=.*?;\sTRACKING)